# RecyclerView scroll speed with offset

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, offset

I want to scroll my `RecyclerView` to a specific position with `offset`. Now I am using `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)` and this method works fine except the scroll happens too fast and I cant control the speed of the scroll. I've tried using `smoothScrollToPosition()` but I need the offset. Can someone tell me how can I control the speed of scrolling when using `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to control fling speed , you need to implement your own recyclerview implementaion .

```
public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    Context context;

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {

        velocityY *= 0.7;
        // velocityX *= 0.7; for Horizontal recycler view. comment velocityY line not require for Horizontal Mode.

        return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

put your `recyclerview` in `nestedScrollview` it will scroll smoothly.

Comment: wow... mine worked anything but smooth, can you please show me how you have used it?? *Curious*

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43255822/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.